# Django DRF : how change to change Date format in my serializer.py?

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I am new to Django DRF and I need a small tip.  My Problem : I want to change the standart models.DateField  to the following format "%d-%m-%Y".  I want to do it for the field "birthday" or in general for the project.

I tried in directlty in the model.py with :

....
birthday = models.DateField(null=True , input_formats= "%d-%m-%Y" ) but it did not work . 
....

I also added in the  setting.py

REST_FRAMEWORK = { "DATE_INPUT_FORMATS": ["%d-%m-%Y"],} but it did not work.

Now i want to try in the serializer.py but given my class I don't know where to do it . 
My serializer.py  looks like that :

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from payload.models import Payload

class PayloadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Payload
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'birthday',]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Create and return a new `payload` instance, given the validated data.
        """
        return Payload.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        """
        Update and return an existing `payload` instance, given the validated data.
        """
        instance.first_name = validated_data.get('first_name', instance.first_name)
        instance.last_name = validated_data.get('last_name', instance.last_name)
        instance.email = validated_data.get('email', instance.email)
        instance.birthday = validated_data.get('birthday',instance.birthday)
        instance.save()

        return instance
```

SO the question : Where  and how do I change in this class the the format of the field birthday ?

Thank you very munch in advance

best

Rémi

Answer (score 1):

add this to your **`settings.py`**

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ["%d-%m-%Y"]
```

Comment: Thank you for your anwer  :)  however it is still not working ahhhhh !!!